# How to call a FK value that is a PK value in another table for SQL server procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have 2 procedures: `usp_inserterpartner` and `usp_insertlocation`.

`usp_insertpartner` inserts a row called `TradingPartnerPK` every time when its called.

`usp_insertlocation` inserts a row with `LocationPK` as the PK and `TradingPartnerFK` as the FK.

How do I exec `usp_insertlocation @TradingPartnerFK = the TradingPartnerPK` in this case??

My current code is the following:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE usp_insertLocation

    @LocationPK int,
    @TradingPartnerFK int,
    @Account varchar (255),
    @Region varchar (255)

    AS
    BEGIN
    SELECT @TradingPartnerFK = Trading_Partner.
    INSERT INTO Location (LocationPK,TradingPartnerFK,Account,Region)
    VALUES (@LocationPK,@TradingPartnerFK,@Account,@Region)

    END

exec usp_insertLocation 1, @TradingPartnerFK = ??????????, 'Nike', 'Americas'
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using of `scope_identity()` with `identity columns` as primary keys example:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce6a4/3)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
create table TradingPartner (
  PartnerPK int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
  SomePartnerData varchar(100)

  )

create table Location(
  LocationPK int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
  TradingPartnerFK int not null,
  SomeLocationData varchar(100),
  foreign key (TradingPartnerFK) references TradingPartner (PartnerPK)
  )

go

create procedure usp_insert_partner
  @SomePartnerData varchar(100)
as
begin
  declare @PartnerPK int
  insert TradingPartner (SomePartnerData) values (@SomePartnerData)
  set @PartnerPK = scope_identity()
  return @PartnerPK
end

go

create procedure usp_insert_location
  @TradingPartnerPK int,
  @SomeLocationData varchar(100)
as
begin
  declare @LocationPK int
  insert Location (TradingPartnerFK, SomeLocationData) 
    values (@TradingPartnerPK, @SomeLocationData)
  set @LocationPK = scope_identity()
  return @LocationPK
end
```

**Query 1**:

```
declare @PartnerPK int

exec @PartnerPK = usp_insert_partner 'Some Partner 1'

exec usp_insert_location @PartnerPK, 'Some Location 1'

exec @PartnerPK = usp_insert_partner 'Some Partner 2'

exec usp_insert_location @PartnerPK, 'Some Location 2'

select *
from Location l
  join TradingPartner p on l.TradingPartnerFK = p.PartnerPK
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ce6a4/3/0)**:

```
| LOCATIONPK | TRADINGPARTNERFK | SOMELOCATIONDATA | PARTNERPK | SOMEPARTNERDATA |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|          5 |                4 |  Some Location 1 |         4 |  Some Partner 1 |
|          6 |                5 |  Some Location 2 |         5 |  Some Partner 2 |
```

Answer (score 2):

`SCOPE_IDENTITY()` will return the latest identity created for the last statement in the current scope.

More information here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms190315(v=sql.100).aspx

---

The way you will be able to use it actually depends on how you are doing the insert.

**If you are within the first StoredProcedure and use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` as I said before :**

Since you can't use a function in your `exec` command you will have to do something like this :

```
declare @fkid int 
set @fkid = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
exec usp_insertLocation 1, @TradingPartnerFK = @fkid, 'Nike', 'Americas'
```

**If the second precedure is called from an outside process such as :**

```
exec usp_insertpartner [...]
exec usp_insertlocation [...]
```

You will have to use `@@identity` since you are outside of the initial scope.

So your call would look like this :

```
exec usp_insertLocation 1, @TradingPartnerFK = @@identity, 'Nike', 'Americas'
```

Comment: I guess my follow up question upon implementing SCOPE_IDENTITY() would be..how would the exec usp_insertLocation look like?? or is there no use for it

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this in separate SP's, your usp_inserterpartner should return the Scope_Identity() value (PK of partner) after it executes an insert statement or use an output parameter to hold this value.

Then when you execute the location sp, the PK value is available either as the return value of usp_inserterpartner or one of it's output parameters.